# Windows 7 cursor lags when playing flash video

Tags: windows-7, flash, cursor, lag

I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop and after upgrading to the latest graphics driver from Windows Update, I have been experiencing one major problem bugging. Here are my specs by the way:

- Pentium M 1.86Ghz
- 1.5GB 667Mhz RAM
- ATI Mobility Radeon x600 (64mb
  dedicated, 596mb shared)

The reason why I upgraded to the latest driver from the old 2006 one is because I was having really bad OpenGL problems, like things literally running 50x slower than they should. Upgrading to the latest driver seems to have fixed the problem, but now whenever I try to play a Flash video (Flash 10.1 is my version), the video plays fine but the cursor is really choppy and jumps all over the place! It really is annoying especially when a site is filled with flash ads.

Comment: This seems to also happen when loading large images on the web. This problem appears on any browser, to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you have Flash offload to the video card? Or turn off offloading if it's enabled? Either having it on or off could cause a problem.

The fact that it also happens with large images makes me think that it is a driver issue.

Can you see if there is a Win7 driver from the OEM for that laptop? That would be your best bet, as far as I know. I have had numerous problems with ATI drivers being updated through Windows Update.