# Mouse and videos lagging

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, lag

For unknown reasons my computer lags at times. It happens in Google chrome and watching some videos. It will randomly lag, not very often but when it does its annoying. The video stutters and mouse slows down.

I re-installed Google Chrome and it helped but the problem is back. This was only 2 days ago, not sure what I can do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 cursor lags when playing flash video](http://superuser.com/questions/92990/windows-7-cursor-lags-when-playing-flash-video) also check out answers at [How to diagnose repeated freezing of windows 7 (comes back alive in few seconds)](http://superuser.com/questions/43389/how-to-diagnose-repeated-freezing-of-windows-7-comes-back-alive-in-few-seconds)

Comment: Hi @Morinr, welcome to SuperUser. There really isn't anywhere near enough information in this question to be able to answer it sensibly I'm afraid. You need to give the specification of the computer and the other software that might be active.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please give some more information about your PC (e.g. specs)

Anyway, it looks to me as a simple memory issue. I used to have the same issue, when many programs (talking about 1/2 programs) were open and I open up another program the PC stutters and you get a bad input lagg from your mouse and this soon finishes. This bumps up your CPU usage high causing the problem, strictly to optimize RAM usage (as it runs out of RAM) which leads to the issue. am I right? Or it could be continuous.

Basic issue, how much RAM do you have? And what OS are you running? Try seizing on some background applications otherwise my best bet would be to get some additional ram. If you have 1GB of RAM it is far too low for modern applications holding in mind there are many background processes as well.

Hope this gave you some insight.

Comment: Ok well currently I have a new computer I built a few months ago.
8 gigs ram
intel 3570k
Nvidia 670
So I don't think it is hardware. I can play games and such. I just found some stuff saying it might be some conflich with flash player on computer and flash player in chrome.

Comment: What are the specs (specifications) if I may ask :)